# Dispatch Express.js route based on first parameter?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm creating a CMS in node.js and Express. I allow users to create their own subsections in the site. A subsection can be a blog, a page or a forum. These sub-sections can be installed one level deep in the site url path, so for instance:

```
domain.com/custom-path-blog/
```

I would have to support the following url structure with express routes:

```
domain.com/custom-path-blog/ -> blog index
domain.com/custom-path-blog/page/5 -> list posts on page 5
domain.com/custom-path-blog/guides/ -> list posts that belong to guides category
domain.com/custom-path-blog/guides/this-is-a-post -> shows a post
```

I would also have to support other sub-sections with different url structures. I have to make a call to a database to check out what the first level in the url actually is before I can dispatch it to the appropriate route.

Since this is a saaas website I dont want to dynamically register the routes on my node process as I could end up having thousands of users with possibly millions of routes. This is not doable. I have to go to the database for that first chunk of information.

Once I know a sub section is a blog or a forum or a e-commerce store how do I send the url past that "custom-path-blog" to be processed by the appropriate express routing mechanism?

I'm starting to think this might be too complicated to do with express routes and I will have to do it by hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already have 3 separated apps (page, blog, forum), and you want to launch it in 1 node process you can do this:

```
app.use('/page', pageApp);
app.use('/blog', blogApp);
app.use('/forum', forumApp);
```

express will strip out the first component of url for you.

---

In your case, the first component is customize by user, so you need to write a middleware for it:

```
function appSelector(req, res, next) {
    var firstComponent = getFirtCompoent(req.url.pathname) // return page or blog ...
    var userID = req.user.id;
    detectAppForCurrentUser(firstCompoent, userID, function (type) {
        if(type === 'page') {
           removeFirstComponent(req);
           return pageApp(req, res, next); 
        }

        if(type === 'blog') {
           removeFirstComponent(req);
           return blogApp(req, res, next); 
        }

        next(); // if not found continue with other routes
    }
}

app.use(appSelector);
// TODO other routes here
```

---

there are many way to solve problem, but is it important rule: **app.use, app.get are called on initialization phase only**

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. What do you mean by initialization phase? Will the appSelector function be called on every request? Regards.

Comment: initialization phase mean when you start process, it should call before app.listen. appSelector will be called on every request but it will not be called if there is a higher priority middleware that call res.end()